# Query Azure table based on Timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

I tried to build a query for azure table storage based on timestamp value in my nodejs server side code.

```
  from = from + 'T00:00:01.000Z';
  to = to + 'T00:00:01.000Z';

  var query = new azure.TableQuery()
    .where('Timestamp ge datetime ? and Timestamp lt datetime ? and deviceId eq ?', from,to,deviceSelected);
```

but i am getting error like,

```
  name: 'StorageError',
  message: 'Syntax error at position 48 in \'Timestamp ge datetime \'2017-11-01T00:00:01.000Z\' and Timestamp lt datetime \'2017-11-02T00:00:01.000Z\' and deviceId eq \'Device1\'\'.\nRequestId:587c0e7d-0002-0090-436f-63abda000000\nTime:2017-11-22T08:57:48.4313529Z',
  code: 'InvalidInput',
  statusCode: 400,
  requestId: '587c0e7d-0002-0090-436f-63abda000000' }
```

can anyone help how to fire build and fire query?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between datetime and the value. `where (... ge datetime?...`

Comment: Yes correct. Now received the data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a side note: Never query on Timestamp attribute as this attribute is not indexed. Please make sure that your query includes `PartitionKey` for efficient querying.

Comment: Second Gaurav. Please refer to this doc regarding how to design your Azure table with high query performance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#log-tail-pattern

Comment: Thanks Gaurav and Lu for the information